# Jquery Keypress is not working for my input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#epFilter").keypress(function(){
        query = $("#epFilter").val();
        alert(query);
});
```

In this code, whenever I type in my text box, it always alert one character less. It doesn't catch the last character. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup) event instead.

```
$("#epFilter").keyup(function(){
        query = $("#epFilter").val();
        alert(query);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`keypress` event is triggered when user presses a key, but before the character is inserted. Use `keyup` event instead.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly improving *Matt's* answer (using `this` inside event handler):

```
$("#epFilter").keyup(function(){
    query = $(this).val();
    alert(query);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if that is a "normal" behavior. Shouldn't keypress be similar to keydown+keyup (except for the codes and keys)?

I had the same problem. I have an input-text field and I want to calculate a total on keypress. However, it does not change the total until I input again another character (this means when I entered the first digit it didn't update). I used "keyup" and was "fixed", but I think it could be better if I use keypress as it doesn't fire when I press other keys (like Ctrl, Shift, arrows, etc).

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) Keypress should work as I expected but for some reason it didn't.

This is not exactly an answer (so don't vote for it). Just my contribution.

Comment: *Shouldn't keypress be similar to keydown+keyup (except for the codes and keys)?*: no, because if you hold the button for a while it will generate several `keypress` events with frequency depending on your OS settings. So you can get: `keydown` -> `keypress` -> `keypress` -> `keypress` -> ... -> `keyup`.